# Does anybody know any good video tutorial for Emacs (basics)?

Tags: emacs

Does anybody know any good video tutorial for Emacs (basics)? I found very good tutorials for Vim in [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6WCm6z5msk&feature=related) and [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/7129986). But for some reason, emacs's video tutorials have all bad quality (can't even read the code).

Any suggestions? (I know you can call me lazy reader)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140336/where-can-i-find-a-video-of-a-pro-using-emacs here is probably the best collection http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/EmacsScreencasts

Comment: also related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393787/any-good-emacs-intro-videos

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but I suggest browsing the [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/). You can usually find information there on any Emacs feature / mode / ... that you can think of, plus you can ask questions if you can't figure something out. It also has a [newbie page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsNewbie) for new comers in case you have no past Emacs experience. And finally, the [Nifty Tricks](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsNiftyTricks) page is full of tips that are appropriate even to more seasoned Emacs users.

Regarding Emacs screencsts, I've watched a bunch of them (mostly about specific editing modes like the erlang-mode or slime) and most of them are unfortunately of questionable image quality. But have a look at the ones mentioned [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsScreencasts), maybe you'll get lucky. Also, there's a PeepCode screen cast which, I'm sure if of good quality, but it costs $9.00.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to checkout emacsmovies.org, which has decent number of videos on emacs